# Reinstalling Windows 11 in my laptop

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-installation, windows-insider, windows-11-v22h2

My laptop has many problems due to the Windows Insider. My laptop is HP Spectre x360-15, and it comes with Windows preinstalled, as well as a variety of programs. I am thinking about reinstalling Windows to go back to a stable version. So, I want to know if I tried to reinstall Windows with the installation media, would this be the correct way? Will this method spoil the activation of windows? Will pre-installed programmes disappear?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to google this before asking? What did your research turn up?

Comment: What build are you on exactly?  If you are on a higher build than 21H2 or 22H2 the only way to resolve your issues is to perform a fresh installation of Windows 11.  Windows 11 is activated with a digital entitlement system, your eligible license key, is automatically detected during the installation process.

Comment: my build  is 22622.601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling Windows 11 version 22H2, replacing the Insider version,
is the only way to a stable system.

There will be no problem with the license/activation, as Microsoft
will recognize your device by its hardware and will activate itself
automatically after the installation. This is called digital entitlement.

For more information see
[How activation works in Windows 10: Digital license vs. product key](https://pureinfotech.com/how-activation-works-windows-10-digital-entitlement-vs-product-key/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It comes with **Windows 11 Home Single Language**. Would the activation be affected if I tried to install **Windows 11 Home**?

Comment: No problem, the activation is now by the hardware fingerprint.